# how to handle when the win cmd line input using python?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I need a script which can take input via command line. I used 'you-get' for download videos.

my code :

```
import subprocess import call

Url='http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm29944115'
call('you-get '+Url, shell=True)
```

result :

```
>>> call('you-get '+Url, shell=True)
User:
```

I input Username & enter.

```
>>> call('you-get '+Url, shell=True)
User: username123
Password:
```

I input Password & enter.

```
>>> call('you-get '+Url, shell=True)
User: username123
Password: pass123

...download success!
```

I'm trying to make an auto compiler for a file using 'you-get'.
I trying, this code didn't work.

```
call('you-get '+Url+' User:user123 Password:123', shell=True)
```

I need your help...
thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: why do you enter "user:" and "password:"? is it required? don't you need to enter as input to 'you-get' : "user123\n123"?

Comment: but nicovideo's download case is required

Comment: error is nothing. same result...

Comment: Instead of using `.call`, take a look at `.run` and [`.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?subprocess.Popen.communicate#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and their `input` parameter.